# select2 apply styles to select

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-select2

I am including select2 from the cdn and applying it to my select multiple input:

my javascript:

```
$('select').select2();
```

my html:

```
<select id = "cars" name="cars[]" multiple = "multiple" required = "required">
```

my css:

```
#cars{
   background-color:red !important;
}
```

For some reason, whenever I apply select2 to any select I have, all the specific styles I give to this select no longer appears. I tried to specify those styles via id and class and they all show but when I put `$('select').select2();` whatever style i specify for this select does not show.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Inspect the rendered select - I suspect select2 will hide your select and create it's own which you must style override - in fact I just looked and it replaces the select - example here http://jsfiddle.net/ishanbakshi/fyhsz9ra/

Comment: @DarrenSweeney u're right i didnt find my style to this select. how do i fix it?

Comment: Posted answer with example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select2 hides selects and re-renders

[Example fiddle here with red background](http://jsfiddle.net/studiotime/4jrgdgL5/)

Css applied:

```
.select2-drop {
  background: red; /* !important not needed */
}
```

[Fiddle with newer version of select2 (4.0.3)](http://jsfiddle.net/studiotime/4jrgdgL5/1/)

Css applied:

```
.select2-dropdown {
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: Well the fiddle does what you want so maybe there's something else in your code that's affecting it

Comment: maybe cause u're using an older version ? I'm using version  4.0.3

Comment: okay now it worked... but do u know how to apply the styles to the elements of the dropdown menu, not the dropdown menu as a whole ?

Comment: Yeah just change your class to: `.select2-dropdown li {
  background: red;
}`

Answer (score 0):

select2 set select display to none and create almost like this element:

```
<span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--below select2-container--focus" dir="rtl" style="width: 97px;"><span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="select2-c968-container"><span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-c968-container" title="ظرفیت - بیشترین">ظرفیت - بیشترین</span><span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></span></span><span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
```

you have to use inspect element to change style. set select { ... } could not help anymore because the select element display set to none by select2.js.

Comment: where does this span appear?

Comment: After your select tag